# Foreign Key for select drop down

Tags: angularjs

So I have data Foo that has a field for bar_ID.

I'm looking at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select and I'm not sure how to populate/preselect an option by value and set the model by the value in the select.

HTML:

```
Bar:<select ng-model="foo.bar_ID" data-ng-options="bar.name for bar in bars track by bar.ID"></select>
foo.bar_ID: {{foo.bar_ID}}
```

JS:

```
$scope.foo = { bar_ID: 2 };
$scope.bars = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        name: "the first"
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
        name: "the second"
    },
    {
        ID: 3,
        name: "the third"
    }];
```

I was expecting :

- to see "the second" selected by default, **but instead** it's `?`
- that I select something, like "the first", `foo.bar_ID` would become `2`, **but instead** it's actually becoming the object associated with the second bar.

Even though the HTML is actually becoming what I expected:

```
<option value="1">the first</option>
```

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s75hjao2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s75hjao2/1/

The syntax for the `ng-options` is `value as text for object in objects` - where `value` is what you set your model equal to to get the option selected. So you want:

```
<select ng-model="foo.bar_ID" data-ng-options="bar.ID as bar.name for bar in bars"></select>
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you can grab the ID out directly out of the same object that's being passed around by reference. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/s75hjao2/4/

Comment: True enough @Antiga, but then (in my real case) I'd have to modify that property in the foo object before sending it off to be updated in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your ng-options
"bar.ID as bar.name for bar in bars"